# Importing Excel Sheet to DataGridView with "Text" or "String"

Tags: c#, .net

I have an excel sheet that contains fields such as "1_2". When importing this sheet to my application with the below code, that particular cell is not imported. I tried cloning my initial datatable and changing my columns to strings, but I given that the initial datatable isn't accepting "1_2", the cloned table also does not contain "1_2".

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Title = "Select File", Filter = "Excel WorkBook|*.xlsx|Excel WorkBook 97-2003|*.xls|All Files(*.*)|*.*", Multiselect = false, ValidateNames = true })
                {
                    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        String SheetName = "Sheet1";
                        String PathName = ofd.FileName;
                        String FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName);

                        string strConn = string.Empty;

                        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(PathName);
                        if (!file.Exists) { throw new Exception("Error, file doesn't exists!"); }
                        string extension = file.Extension;
                        switch (extension)
                        {
                            case ".xls":
                                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + PathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                                break;
                            case ".xlsx":
                                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + PathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                                break;
                            default:
                                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + PathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                                break;
                        }
                        using (OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
                        {
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("select * from [{0}$]", SheetName), cnnxls))
                            {//CLONING AND CONVERTING TO STRING COLUMNS - THIS DOESN'T QUITE WORK
                                oda.Fill(dtDataImportInitial);
                                dtDataImport = dtDataImportInitial.Clone();
                                foreach (DataColumn col in dtDataImport.Columns)
                                {
                                    col.DataType = typeof(string);
                                }
                                foreach (DataRow row in dtDataImportInitial.Rows)
                                {
                                    dtDataImport.ImportRow(row);
                                }
                                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtDataImport;
                            }
                        }                                         
                    }
                }
```

Is there any way to change my import process so that fields such as "1_2" are accepted?

Comment: Assuming `dtDataImportInitial` can be just a `new DataTable()` and that `dataGridView1` is a typical `DataGridView` control.  If a cell contains `1_2` it is imported as the text `1_2`, so I'm not sure if maybe it's a locale thing for you?  Why is `1_2` special?  What I'm saying is ... I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Wyck Ah - it seems related to the cell format on the excel sheet :(.

Comment: Usually issues occurs when you have an empty row/column on the spreadsheet excel will stop.  The IMEX=1 should solve these issues.  Also Jet is more vulnerable to these issues.  So does issue occur with both xls and xlsx?

Comment: @jdweng Yes, it does. I find that if I change the cell formats on the excel sheet to "text" it completely avoids this issue. I've been trying to avoid having to do this, but google searches have remained unfruitful.

Comment: Try double quotes instead of single quotes : Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\"";

Comment: @jdweng That causes an error given the format of my code, since you'd be effectively closing the quotes prematurely.

                                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + PathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";

Comment: Where are the two backslashes  before the double quotes like in my comment?

Comment: @jdweng Ah - missed that. Alright, added the backslashes and the quotes, and still no go :/

Comment: Are you getting error, or still not getting the text?

Comment: Still not getting the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to the cell format of the excel sheet itself.